# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}$

Since $\frac{k}{n^2+k^2}\leq \frac{k}{k^2+k^2}=\frac{1}{2k}$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$.

Now we send $n$ to infinity, then since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ is harmonic, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}$ doesn't exist.

I wonder if my thinking is right.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Sorry, the previous title is auto-saved. I have corrected it.

Comment: All you have shown is that the sum is bounded above by the harmonic series, which you know diverges to infinity. That _does not_ mean that the limit of the sum under consideration doesn't exist.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, but here is a new one: It seems you have shown your series is bounded *above* by a series that diverges to infinity. But this is not enough to conclude anything about your series...

Comment: If $5 < \infty$ is $5$ infinite?

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I think I've made a silly mistake. I will ponder on it for a while.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I use $\sum \frac{k}{n^2+1}$ and $\sum \frac{k}{2n^2}$ to bound the series and I think the limit is between $1/2$ and $1/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+ k^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2(1+(k/n)^2)}= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k/n}{(1+(k/n)^2)}$$
This corresponds to a certain integration. Calculate that.

Comment: Do you the integration is $\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx$?

Comment: @SHBaoS: Yes exaclty, with the lower limit $0$ and the upper limit $1$.

Comment: But what about the $\frac{1}{n}$ outside the summation? The integral is $\frac{1}{2}ln(2)$, but if $n$ goes to $\infty$, then shouldn't $\frac{1}{n}$ go to zero?

Comment: @SHBaoS: Do you know what is Riemann integration. Can you recall how do we get from such limit sum to an integral, I mean how do we prove that the limit sum is an integral. You may find your answer there. You may also think intuitively as the integral representing the area under a curve, and as the 'width' $1/n$ shrinks to $0$ you approach the area ever so closer.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the fun.*

Consider $$S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{(n^2+ik)(n-ik)}=\frac i2  \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n+i k}-\frac{1}{n-i k} \right)$$ Using generalized harmonic numbers $$S_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(-H_{-i n}-H_{i n}+H_{(1-i) n}+H_{(1+i) n}\right)$$ Using asymptotics $$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ and applying to each term, after simplifications, you should end with $$S_n=\frac{\log (2)}{2}+\frac{1}{4 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Use it with $n=10$ which gives $$S_{10}=\frac{2892380100711541}{7801656832544900}\approx 0.370739$$ while the expansion gives $$S_{10}\approx\frac{\log (2)}{2}+\frac{193}{8400}\approx 0.369550$$